# O(1) access to depth 3 tree with high branching factor

Tags: data-structures

I have a tree of depth 3 with a high branching factor. Let's say for example the first layer contains all the taxonomic genera, the second level all the species and the third level contains data regarding the species.
Or graphically:

```
         genus1         genus2         ...         genus70000
        /   |   \      /   |   \                  /     |    \
      sp1  sp2  sp3   sp4  sp5 sp6           sp330k sp330k+1  sp330k+2
      |    |    |     |    |    |              |       |        |
  data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6   data330k data330k+1 data330k+2
```

In reality there are about five species per genus on average and not 3 but it doesn't really matter. I want to store this data in such a manner to support the following operations in `O(1)` (assuming that the number of species in each genus is constant):

1. Get data related to species `s`
2. Get data for all species in genus `g`
3. Insert to species `s` whose genus is `g` with data `d`

My current implementation stores a hash map between the genera and a list of pairs of species belonging to each genus and the data associated with that species. In this scheme operations `2` and `3` run in `O(1)` but operation `1` must iterate over all the genera in order to find the one that contains species `s`.

I was wondering what would be a better data structure for this.

**Edit**

Solving this problem while doubling the memory required is easy. I could just store a separate hash map from the species to their data. It would be nice if I could do this without storing the tree twice.

P.S.

I am writing in Java7 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an extra `HashMap` that maps from `s` to `g`.

Comment: Yeah, that would work but it would double my memory footprint. I could also just store two hashmaps. One from g->s->d and one just from s->d. Is there a way to do it without doubling the memory?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a multi-dimensional data structure with 3 dimensions for data, genus and sp. 
For example: kd-Tree, R-tree, or PH-Tree.
Not sure how well these work, though.

PH-tree works best with larger datasets with 10^6 entries or more. But it is partially oblivious of the number of dimensions, because they are internally processed in 'transposed' 64bit strings.

Anyway, you would have to try it out.

Disclaimer: [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) is my own data structure.